# Erro com prechimento e submit de campos via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
$('#grupo_prod').blur(function(){
   
   var grupo = $('#grupo_prod').val();
   var filial = $('#filialAtual').val();

   $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: base_url+"pdv2/selecionarProduto/",
    dataType: "html",
    data: { grupo: grupo, filial: filial}
    })
    .done(function( response ) {

    $('#produto_desc').html(response);
    $('#produto_desc').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled" );
    //document.getElementById('prod_desc').focus();
    $('#produto_desc').select2('open');
    
    });
   
});

$('#produto_desc').change(function(){
   
   var prod = $('#produto_desc').val();
   var filial = $('#filialAtual').val();

   $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: base_url+"pdv2/estoqueProdutoId/",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { produto: prod, filial: filial}
    })
    .done(function( response ) {
    $("#estoque").text(response[0].produto_estoque);    
    $("#valor_unit").val(response[0].produto_preco_venda);
    $("#pvm").text(response[0].produto_preco_minimo_venda);
    $("#pcd").text(response[0].produto_preco_cart_debito);
    $("#pcc").text(response[0].produto_preco_cart_credito);
    
   // document.getElementById('quantidade').focus();
    $("#quantidade").focus();
    // $('#quantidade').select2('open');
    
    });
    
    $('#total-item').blur(function(){
   
   var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val();
   var subTotal = $('#total-item').val();
   var venda  = $('#idVenda').val();
   var produto = $('#produto_desc').val();
   var filial = $('.filialAtual').text();

   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: base_url+"pdv2/additensVendas/",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: { quantidade: quantidade, subTotal: subTotal, venda: venda, produto: produto, filial: filial },
      success: function(data)
       {
         if(data.result == true){
           location.reload();
         }
         else{
           alert('Quantidade sem estoque!');
         }
       }
      
    });
   
});
```

Tenho o código acima aonde mesmo faz um consulta via ajax e preenche uns campos e após o preenchimento dos campos, a ultima função do código inserir os dados no banco de dados. O Problema e que se usuário por exemplo pesquisa duas vezes um grupo o ajax esta inserindo duas vezes mesmo tendo só um valor nos campos, eu reparei que cada vez que o usario passa na função `$('#produto_desc').change(function()` faz essas duplicidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está colocando eventos dentro de eventos. Por exemplo, está colocando `$('#total-item').blur(function(){` dentro do `$('#produto_desc').change(function(){`. Isso faz com que, cada vez que o evento change for disparado, seja criada uma nova instância do evento blur.

O certo mesmo é que cada evento esteja separado um do outro, tipo:

```
$('#produto_desc').change(function(){
 ...
});

$('#total-item').blur(function(){
...
});
```

Ou então você poderia deixar o código como está, usando o `.one()`, que cria a instância apenas uma vez, trocando o `$('#total-item').blur(function(){` por:

```
$('#total-item').one("blur", function(){
```

Comment: Flw amigo não tinha prestado atenção que os eventos estava um dentro do outro,